# Upsert in MongoDB causes repeated inserts through pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am attempting to use upserts in MongoDB. For some reason, the `pymongo.Collection.update` method is inserting new documents (each time) when it should be updating the pre-existing documents.

Here is my code:

```
print self.visitorCollection.find({"ip": user_ip, "userAgent": user_agent}).count()
self.visitorCollection.update(
        {"ip": user_ip, "userAgent": user_agent},
        {"$set": {"last_request": currentTime}, "$inc": {"requests": 1}, "$setOnInsert": {"first_request": currentTime, "userAgent": user_agent}},
        upsert = True
        ) # currently not working properly
```

When integrated into my `Flask` application, this is the output that I receive:

```
12
13
14
```

As you can see, it is continually adding new documents even when it should be just updating the original.

I appreciate any insight on this!

**Edit: As it turns out, this code works correctly and the bug cannot be reproduced - it was caused by other code in my application that is not shown here**.

Comment: not sure what may be the problem, but anyway `update` is depricated, can you try using `update_many`?

Answer (score 1):

You have `upsert: True` in you query and when `upsert: True` mongo perform an insert if no documents match the filter.

Quoting the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db-collection-update)

**upsert**

> Optional. If set to true, creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria. The default value is false, which does not insert a new document when no match is found.

Comment: That's the issue - I want it to update a document (there should only be one that matches the filter) when the filter is matched.

On the first request from a user, the document should be inserted. But on subsequent requests, that document should be updated. I can do this on an application-level, but that will take a hit to performance and this *should* be doable with a single query.

Based on the count of documents, you can see that it is matching the query repeatedly.